# beautiful soup captures null values in a table

Tags: html-table, beautifulsoup

For the following piece of HTML code, I used beautifulsoup to capture the  table information:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Code</b></td>
<td><b>Display</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>min</td>
<td>Minute</td><td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>happy </td>
<td>Hour</td><td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>daily </td>
<td>Day</td><td/>
</tr>
```

This is my code:

```
comments = [td.get_text()  for td in table.findAll("td")]
Comments=[data.encode('utf-8')  for data in comments]
```

As you see, this table has two headers: "code and display" and some values in rows. The expected output of my code should be [code, display, min, minutes, happy, Hour, daily, day]

but this is the output:

```
['Code', 'Display', 'min', 'Minute', '', 'happy ', 
'Hour', '', 'daily ', 'Day', '']
```

The output has  '' in 5th,  8th, and 11th indices in comments that are not defined in this table. I think it may because of `</td><td/>`.
How can I change the code to not capture u'' in the output?

Comment: @Noah, my problem is not 'u'. It is u' ' in the output list. After I turn the code to string using the following code: 'Comments=[data.encode('utf-8')  for data in comments]', this is the output: ['Code', 'Display', 'min', 'Minute', '', 'happy ', 'Hour', '', 'daily ', 'Day', ''] , can you see the extra output in 5th, and 10th indices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I hadn't read your question carefully enough. You're right, the problem is the empty `<td/>` tags. Just adjust your generator to only include cells with text:

```
comments = [td.get_text() for td in table.findAll('td') if td.text]
```

---

**EDIT:** I doubt this is the most efficient way to do it, but this will only include tds that have either text or a corresponding td in the first row.

```
ths = table.tr.find_all('td')
tds_in_row = len(table.tr.next_sibling.find_all('td'))

tds = [
    td.get_text()
    for i, td in enumerate(table.find_all('td'))
    if len(ths) > (i + 1) % tds_in_row or td.text
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Sorry Noah, can you give me another solution?  Because if I use the code you offered , it will not capture some of the null values (for example for display in other tables) that I really want to capture them. do you think I can remove the <td/> from the table tags?

Comment: Can you give examples of when you would and would not want to keep the values?

Comment: for example in the following url, definition column of the table in the section of content logical definition  has null values.
 
 https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-contract-term-type.html


But for the following URL: 
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-age-units.html

Table (in the content logical definition section) returns null values while no column defined in the table that includes null value. Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Thank you so much ! For this part of your code "tds_in_row = len(table.tr.next_sibling.find_all('td'))", this is the error:'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all

Comment: @Mary It's probably picking up newline characters ('\n') in your table string. Either make sure that the table doesn't contain any line breaks, or use find_next_sibling('tr') instead of next_sibling.