# Beautiful soup just extract header of a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract information from the table in the following website using beautiful soup in python 3.5.

```
http://www.askapatient.com/viewrating.asp?drug=19839&name=ZOLOFT
```

I have to save the web-page first, since my program needs to work off-line.

I saved the web-page in my computer and I used the following codes to extract table information. But the problem is that the code just extract heading of the table.

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "file:///Users/MD/Desktop/ZoloftPage01.html"


home_page= urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(home_page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"ratingsTable" } )
comments = [td.get_text() for td in table.findAll("td")]
print(comments)
```

And this is the output of the code:

```
['RATING', '\xa0 REASON', 'SIDE EFFECTS FOR ZOLOFT', 'COMMENTS', 'SEX', 'AGE', 'DURATION/DOSAGE', 'DATE ADDED ', '\xa0’]
```

I need all the information in the table’s rows. 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the *broken HTML* of the page. You need to switch to a more *lenient parser* like [`html5lib`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Here is what works for me:

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.askapatient.com/viewrating.asp?drug=19839&name=ZOLOFT"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'})

# HTML parsing part
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"ratingsTable"})
comments = [[td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")] 
            for row in table.find_all("tr")]
pprint(comments)
```

Comment: thank you so much ! I am using python 3.5. The code has the following error:  "ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'"

Comment: @Mary the downloading the page source part is actually not relevant here. But, if you want to use the example as is, you would need to have [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) installed.

Comment: I highly appreciate it. Thank you so much !